# A duplicated name Audience was found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection, team-sites, features

Whenever I try to activate the `"SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"` feature in my site collection with Team Site template I get the message on the page saying that

> A duplicate name Audience was found

I don't understand why it is showing up but I need this feature to be activated.

Site Collection is accessed from the client browser and I have no access to PowerShell or Visual Studio.

I need help guys, anything soon is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the error message is *"A duplicate Field name "Audience" was found" *or *A duplicate name Audience was found*, if it includes field so Try to Check if this column "Audience" already exists or not in *Site Settings > Site Columns.* if there, try to delete it

Comment: "A duplicate Field name "Audience" was found" - This is the message

Comment: There is a column name which is not exactly same as Audience but part of the column matching found as "MyHR Audience"

Comment: if it's not important try to delete it and try again to activate the publishing feature

Comment: Ok,I found two site columns and I was able to delete one, but for the other I couldn't delete it and it says it can't delete it because it may have been used in other lists and libraries. Its a brand new site collection and there is no list that is using this site column

Comment: I tried deleting one site column but the other wouldn't delete because it was associated to Doc Content Type..  I tried activating the feature now and I get this new error message " Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to provision role definitions. OriginalException: Value does not fall within the expected range. "